# Comparison between 4 groups of 10 samples

Tags: anova

Comparing differences in 4 groups of 10 patients. Differences relate to (simplistically) the number of bacteria each patient carries. This is a novel comparison with no precedent.

Does this make it impossible to power (given no precent, unknown siginificance between groups)?

If to compare- would an ANOVA be the way?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make it impossible to do power analysis, it just means that you have to figure out what effect size would be large enough to be meaningful but small enough to be possible.

If the number of bacteria is fairly high, then ANOVA should be fine, but if it is relatively low, you might want a count regression model such as Poisson regression or negative binomial regression.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Sorry about the typo- mean to say given no precedent, we have no idea of the effect size at all :(

Comment: Then, yes, power analysis is impossible.  But if you are doing research in the field, you should be able to make some sort of guess.